# How do I fix a div during scroll relative to Squarespace image blocks?

Tags: javascript, css, squarespace

I'm trying to fade in/out and fix the blue div on the left when scrolled relative to the image blocks on the right.

http://www.warface.co.uk/#/testing/
pass: squared

```
.meta { /*This is the block I'm trying to stick/*
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    width: 372px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Use `.meta` first. It is a class, right?

Comment: Yes, its using .meta, see the live example

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basics in JavaScript:

```
function controlMeta() {
    var meta = document.querySelector("div.meta");
    console.log(meta);
    if (window.scrollY > 500) {
        meta.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        meta.style.display = "block";
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    controlMeta();
})
```

You can get your elements scroll position with something like this:

```
document.getElementById("57513a9220c6475fb77061c5").getBoundingClientRect().top+window.scrollY
```

**EDIT 1**

Here is a method for associating elements with the meta box, based upon the previous:

```
//Load elements that affect the meta box
var meta = [];
var images = document.querySelector('.sqs-gallery').getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    meta.push({
        node : images[i],
        height : images[i].height,
        //top is used with scroll position to determine which element we are looking at
        top : images[i].getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY
    });
}
function controlMeta() {
    meta.filter(function (el) {
        //You might need to pad your filter a little
        return window.scrollY < el.top && window.scrollY > el.top - el.height;
    }).forEach(function (el) {
        //These are the matching elements. I'm just fetching the src as an example
        document.querySelector("div.meta div.body").innerHTML = el.node.src;
    });
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    controlMeta();
});
```